# Removing animation sprite frames from layer?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Let's say I have a character in a game and its class is like this.

```
@interface Player
{
  CCSprite* stand;
  CCAnimation* run;
}

-(void) playRunAction
{
  // Create CCAnimate* object from CCAnimation object (run)

  [self runAction:runAniate];
}

-(void) playStandAction
{
  stand.visible = YES;
  [self stopAllActions];
}
```

The player has ability to stand or run.

But one problem is, after playStandAction is called, stand animation is visible and running animation stopped, but one frame of running animation still there!
( Now you see 'stand sprite' AND 'one of running animation frame' together. )

How can I make running animation not visible?

P.s Can anyone throw me a better way of managing animation in one character? This is totally disaster as animations added.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) playStandAction
{
//Make the animation object.visible = NO; here 
  stand.visible = YES;
  [self stopAllActions];
}
```

and in

```
-(void) playRunAction
{
  // Create CCAnimate* object from CCAnimation object (run)
  //Make the animation object.visible = YES; here
  stand.visible = NO;
  [self runAction:runAniate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method with parameter `restoreOriginalFrame` and pass it `yes`

I don't know which method you are calling for creating `CCAnimate` object...

Like this:

```
[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:YES]];
```

And don't call runAction on layer. I would prefer you to runAction on sprite itself...

You don't need to hide and show 2 different objects...

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Yep, I forgot to put ': CCSprite' next to player class definition. Thanks for the tip. I didn't know restoreOriginalFrame is there. But what if I call stand method in the middle of run animation? or run animation is made of repeat forever?

Comment: I think still den you will get your original frame back... Just cross check once by calling method...